# Doctrine2 ODM - Object ( or Embedded Document ) as _id

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I have a process running an incremental map reduce to a collection where I am looking at metrics over different time periods - grouping by id(s) and date.  So my output collection essentially has a composite id to handle the grouping.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "site" : 67,
        "dt" : ISODate("2012-07-03T00:00:00Z")
    },
    "value" : {
        // Metrics here
    }
}
```

I want to be able to fetch results from this collection in my Symfony2 app using the ODM - but having trouble with the `_id` field. I thought I might be able to specify it as an `@Id` and `@embedOne`:

```
   /**
    * @MongoDB\Id
    * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="reportId")
    */
   protected $id;
```

However, this doesn't work.  I also tried setting `@Id` with `strategy=NONE`, and I can use the QueryBuilder to fetch rows, but it errors when trying to hydrate my Document class. I tried slugging the site id and date ( `67-134137916` ) and it allows me to use the DocumentManager, but I lose the ability to query by date ranges.

Anyone have any input on how to handle an object as an id in Doctrine2's ODM, is this supported?

**edit:**
Removed composite primary key tag - question really pertains to using an object as a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this gets at the heart of your question: [Composite Primary Keys tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

It looks like you can only have composite primary keys of integers and strings (so no dates?).

Comment: Unfortunately this is for the ORM, not ODM.  I did look over this a little while ago though.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I talked to some colleagues and you can't use ISODates as keys in  embedded docs.  Could you convert ISODate to a UTC string? You'd also have to make sure your queries are restructured to do range searches for UTC time.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I actually edited my question to remove the composite key requirement, as I think I was incorrectly applying the terminology here.  Really, in order to group with MapReduce, you end up creating a multi-key object for your collection - I don't believe there is currently any support in Doctrine's ODM code to handle, essentially, an EmbedOne or Hash as a primary key.

Comment: @kmfk: This isn't currently supported. Feel free to open an issue on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) so we can track this feature request.